# no module name pmadarima

Tags: python, arima, pmdarima

On installing `pip install pmdarima` via command prompt as admin, I get the below message as successful installation.

```
Requirement already satisfied: patsy>=0.5 in c:\users\username\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from statsmodels!=0.12.0,>=0.11->pmdarima) (0.5.1)
```

But unable to work on it via Jupyter, get the below error on running

```
import pmdarima as pm

from pmdarima.model_selection import train_test_split

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pmdarima'
```

Comment: Your Jupyter notebook may be using a different interpreter or virtualenv.

Comment: Can you please help in resolving these errors?

Answer (score 0):

When you do `pip install`, you're using your system's default `python`. You can have multiple versions of Python installed on the same computer.

For example, on my Mac if I do `python` in the terminal that opens Python 2. If I do `python3` in the terminal, that opens Python 3.

When I do `pip install numpy`, it will install it to Python 2 by default. A program running in Python 3 will not be able to find that package.

To get it working for Python 3, I would do `python3 -m pip install numpy`. This uses the pip belonging to the right Python interpreter.

What is most likely happening here is that your Jupyter notebook is using a different Python interpreter. Try doing the install inside the notebook itself in a cell and that should work.